# How can we run 2 python scripts that share a common variable in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

First let me explain the scenario.

My project is built using Django.

I have the frontend wherein we can upload the image of a person. That image will be stored in our local machine in (media folder).

Ex: If the image name is `jon.jpeg`, then it will be stored as

```
media
-jon
--jon.jpeg
```

If another image is uploaded, say `bob.jpg`, then the structure will be like:

```
media
-jon
--jon.jpeg
-bob
--bob.jpg
```

Now I have one Python script (say `check.py`) in which we are running one infinite loop, and every 5 seconds it is checking the number of folders in the media folder. Also, we are maintaining one global variable in `check.py` that will keep track of the initial_count.

Now I have another Python file running (i.e `camera.py`) and it has 2 functions , i.e `load_encodings` and `recognize` in a class called `Face_Recog`.

`load_encodings` will convert the images in the media folder to feature encodings and it will store these encodings in a global list (`known_faces`) in the `camera.py` file.

`recognize` will first extract the image from one camera frame and encode it, and then it will compare it with the encodings in `known_faces`.

Now whenever the number of folders in `media` changes, (if we upload the image from the frontend) , then in our `initial_count` in `check.py` will change. We have given a condition wherein if the `initial_count` value changes,  it will call the `encoding` function of the `camera.py` file.

`check.py`

```py
from camera import Face_Recog,object

initial_count = 0
while True:
    count = 0
    for path in os.listdir(path/to/media):
        count += 1
    global initial_count
    if count != initial_count:
        Face_Recog.load_encodings(object)
        initial_count = count
    sleep(5)
```

`camera.py`

```py
known_faces = []

class Face_Recog(object):
    def load_encodings(self):
        temp = []
        #some code that will change the temp value , i.e it will load the image from media and then encode it and store the encoding in temp
        global known_faces
        known_faces = temp

    def recognize(self):
        while(True):
            #code that uses known_faces and recognizes


object = Face_Recog()
object.load_encodings()
object.recognize()
```

Now I am running these two files in 2 different shells.

Initially the media folder contains only `jon`, so `known_faces` will contain only encodings of `jon`.

```
known_faces = ['jon']
```

and the `recognize` function will not recognize `bob`, it will only recognize `jon`.

(This is working.)

Now when I upload the image of `bob`, the `initial_count` value will change in `check.py` and it will call the `load_encodings` function of `camera.py` (it is calling it; I have checked using print statements).

Now this function will again encode the images present , i.e `jon` and `bob`, and update the global variable, i.e `known_faces`.

(It is updating, but only in the shell in which `check.py` is running, not in the shell running `camera.py`. I.e it is not reflecting the changes in the `camera.py` file's `known_faces` variable, which is running in a different shell instance).

So even if it is changing the `known_faces` variable, the `recognize` function is not recognizing `bob`, i.e the variable (`known_faces`) it is using is not updated automatically.

I want to do something like whenever any person uploads any image from the frontend, its encodings should be updated in the file (`camera.py`) without the camera being stopped i.e `recognize` function should not stop its execution.

PS. NOTE: Both the files, i.e `camera.py` and `check.py` are running all the time in 2 different shells.

Please tell me if it is possible, or is there any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: If you have already run these files, please update your question with your real code.

Comment: You need inter-process communication. There are several mechanisms for IPC; the simplest conceptually is to have both processes monitor a file and load the new value from it when it changes, but this is clunky and slow. Shared memory and pipes are more elegant, but require some amount of learning curve.  If you want to use threading, that's a possibility too, though it will require a similar amount of refactoring of your current code.

Comment: This is actually the simplified example of what I am actually trying to do , should I edit the problem and add the actual problem that I am trying to solve. I am sorry , but I am new here. @tripleee

Comment: At this level of description, we have no idea whether that will make this clearer at all. If you didn't want to actually ask this particular question, by all means do replace it with what you actually wanted to ask; see perhaps also the guidance for providing a [mre] i.e. don't post 2000 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I don't see how this changes anything; basically this is just longer. My second comment still explains what you need.  The absolutely simplest fix for your scenario is probably to have `check.py` monitor the file and restart the other process when necessary. Once the two processes are running, they know nothing about each other, unless you explicitly make them talk to each other. Again, threading is one way to solve that (then there is only one process) but often, threading complicates things more than you would like.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee it worked that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolutely simplest fix for your scenario is probably to have `check.py` monitor the file and restart the other process when necessary.